# Some websites does not allow TOR navigation: how to avoid that?

Tags: tor

I cannot enter some websites using the TOR navigator on windows (or Linux)

ex: http://pagesjaunes.fr/

Is there a way to avoid that ?

Comment: You can avoid this by not using Tor when accessing these sites. If you ask how to access the site by still using Tor you are essentially asking how to bypass security measures employed by these site. But such questions are explicitly off-topic, no matter if one likes such measures or not.

Comment: Find an open proxy or VPN, and use that to access the site. You can use proxychains to automate that.

Answer (score 3):

The list of Tor exit nodes is public, so if a website does not want any visitors from Tor they are free to block access from these IP addresses. There isn't really a way around this except to not use Tor.

You can try to find a trustworthy VPN that the site doesn't block, but you likely won't achieve the same level of anonymity with a VPN as you would with Tor without some careful configuration on your end.

Comment: You can always [tunnel your Tor traffic through a VPN (via dedicated software/hardware)](https://thetinhat.com/tutorials/darknets/tor-vpn-using-both.html). If you can, e.g. run your own VPSes anonymously, this can be far more secure than just using Tor (in certain circumstances) as well as being less likely to be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the reason why you're trying to access all these sites via Tor, but keep in mind that you have to trust the exit node as they could be monitoring your traffic to these sites, e.g. if you're logging in a service, the exit node could record your password as a man in the middle attack. I wouldn't log in any public website via Tor.

In your scenario, you might be able to simply use a VPN like TunnelBear. It's faster, you can control from where you're connecting, might be even more useful if your need is professional to verify how a website behaves when connected from elsewhere. A service like TunnelBear will also have good [privacy promises](https://www.tunnelbear.com/privacy-policy) compared to a Tor exit node you know nothing about.

If you really want to stay in the Tor category, you can try I2P. But even i2p doesn't have many [exit nodes](https://geti2p.net/en/faq#exit) so can be painfully slow.

But if you really want to browse via Tor, you can keep trying to change your identity hoping that one of the exit node's IP address isn't blocked by the site you're visiting. But not very long later your exit node might change back to a blocked IP, so doesn't seem sustainable to me.